# Lisp cyclic lists

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, circular-list

We have been given homework from lisp where I need to use "cyclic" list (I don't know what is the right naming for this). By "cyclic" list, I mean list, where `cdr` of the last one cons points to the very first one of the same list.

```
(Value1 . PointerValue2) (Value2 . PointerValue3) (Value3 . PointerValue1)
```

We have been taught to create such a lists with:

```
(defun cykl (l)
  (setf (cdr (last l)) l)
)
```

The Lisp software (*Lispbox*) I use does not support this kind of lists. I have also tried *clisp* on Debian but it has crashed after creating such a list.

What lisp implementations do you know that does support this (freeware, os independent)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All lisp implementations, including `clisp`, support [*circular* lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#circular_list).

When you say "crashed", you probably mean a [stack overflow error](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-stack) (or an out-of-memory error), which you will always get when you try to *print* (remember the 'read-eval-PRINT' loop?) a circular structure when [`*print-circle*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) is `nil`. Setting it to `t` forces Lisp to use the [#n#](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhp.htm) notation:

```
[1]> (defparameter l (list 1 2 3))
L
[2]> l
(1 2 3)
[3]> (setq *print-circle* t)
T
[4]> (setf (cdr (last l)) l)
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
```

See also [function LIST-LENGTH](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_l.htm)