# how to remove parenthesis from sublists within a list?

Tags: list, common-lisp, flatten

```
(defun ppl (list)
  (loop for x in list
    collect (cons x '(ppl))))
(ppl '(1 2 3))
=> ((1 ppl) (2 ppl) (3 ppl))
```

While still inside `ppl`, how do I remove the parenthesis so that the result becomes

```
=> (1 ppl 2 ppl 3 ppl)
```

I understand that my code fundamentally creates a list of sublists. Could use some help on flattening out the list. Perhaps if I could in some way get the list that collect returns?

Comment: It's not about 'remove parenthesis'. Parentheses are only a thing in an external textual representation of a list. The operation is called 'flatten'. It takes a nested list and returns a new list with a flat list, which then contains all the atoms of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`nconc` instead of `collect`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm):

```lisp
(defun ppl (list)
  (loop for x in list
    nconc (list x 'ppl)))
(ppl '(1 2 3))
==> (1 PPL 2 PPL 3 PPL)
```

Please note that I replaced `(cons x '(ppl))` with `(list x 'ppl))` to avoid possible reuse of literal `(ppl)` which `nconc` could turn into [circular lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15536564/850781). If you *insist* on having [quoted literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) in your code (bad idea!), use `append` instead of `nconc`.